# Update table between 2 max dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 5 columns.

1. id
2. bday
3. update
4. restartDate
5. startDate

I need to update each rows update column with the most recent date between restartDate and startDate

I've tried:

```
update mytable
set update = (select MAX(v)from (values (restartDate),(startDate)) as value(v))
```

But that seems to make the update column current date(like now())

I should also mention that the startDate and restartDate can be null

For example:

| restartDate | startDate | update |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-11 | null | null |

would set update as 2022-11-11

or

| restartDate | startDate | update |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | 2022-11-05 | null |

would set update as 2022-11-05

restartDate cannot be null

Comment: The command you've mentioned doesn't match your description. Could you please add some sample input and expected outcome to make clear what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a few more details. a) Which RDBMS you use e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL MSSQL b) show an excerpt from your data and show how they should change. Thanks

Comment: @Christos this is for sql..

Comment: @sud0 ... that is not an answer to what @Chirstos asked. We know what `SQL` is, at a general level, but what DATABASE do you use? ... the SQL syntax can differ between various DB vendors and versions. Hover the `sql` tag with the mouse for more information.

Comment: I think it's postgressql

Comment: Your update statement works as desired. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/OAwgIoHj

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GREATEST` for that:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET updated = GREATEST(restartDate, startDate);
```

This will already be sufficient if you use Postgres as you said.

Otherwise, if you use MariaDB or MYSQL, you will notice the column "updated" will be null if your startDate is null because their `GREATEST` doesn't handle that. In this case, you can add a `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET updated = GREATEST(restartDate, COALESCE(startDate,restartDate));
```

You can verify it's working correctly here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4b58rLJe)

As you can also verify there is that the update command you've already mentioned is working, too.

Comment: This makes the update column current date.

Comment: Well, this means that the current date is the latest of the two dates.

Comment: It sounds like they may have a trigger setup

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` for conditions.

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET update = CASE
    WHEN restartDate >= COALESCE(startDate,restartDate) THEN restartDate 
    ELSE startDate 
  END
```

Comment: I'm getting ERROR:  column "mt" of relation "mytable" does not exist

Comment: try:
UPDATE mytable AS mt 
  SET mt.update = CASE
    WHEN mt.restartDate > mt.startDate THEN mt.restartDate 
    ELSE mt.startDate 
  END

or without alias "mt"

Comment: Curiously, PostgreSQL, does not allow the alias in `UPDATE mytable mt SET mt.update = ...`, but requires `UPDATE mytable mt SET update = ...` instead. Your update statement doesn't work correctly when startDate is null, though.

Comment: ok, removed alias and added check for null. sad :( what PostgreSQL can't update with alias